# How to hotswap .xhtml files in Intellij with WebSphere

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, websphere, hotswap

I'm migrating from eclipse to IntelliJ. In eclipse, when WebSphere servers are launched and I do changes in .xhtml or .xml (spring web-flow) files, changes can be seen instantly on web browser refresh and no server restart is needed.

An eclipse launch configuration is quite different there was a button "publish" that created project.ear.xml before server launch file which included paths to resources. Haven't found a similar option for Intellij, so using "ear exploded" (.ear not exploded is not the same thing in Intellij compared to Eclipse).

Now in order to launch servers in Intellij, I use "project:ear exploded" artifact which is being built before launch.

When the server is launched with Intellij and I do changes in ".xhtml" file no changes can be seen (hot-swapped), without server restart. In my server configuration, I also have chosen "On 'Update' action: Update classes and resources" (I assume that 'Update' action is build->build artifacts-> build new exploded .ear file). If I use run->update application->update resources it restarts server which is not acceptable because the application I'm using takes a lot of time to do it and even doesn't work properly after that and requires an additional server restart.

Does IntelliJ has any solution similar to eclipse for hot-swapping (instant) resources e.x .xhtml?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#reload_classes

Comment: When I do this it just takes old data from a snapshot I'm using to launch the server.  The problem is - how to avoid building a new snapshot before swapping because it's inconvenient to do it just for one changed .xhtml file and hot-swap changes in the existing snapshot.